# How to view .py in Eclipse

Tags: python, eclipse

I just installed eclipse on my machine and want to modify a .py file. I tried opening the file and I get the error application not found. What do I need to install and how do I install it. I have searched the web and not found any clear instruction. I am using Java Eclipse SDK.

I am trying to open the file .py with Eclipse on windows machine. The error I get is "application not found".

Comment: Is this on Mac? Windows? Linux?

Comment: This question is tough to answer. How did you try opening the file? Via Eclipse? What was the exact error message you got? What OS are you using, Windows, Mac, Linux, etc etc. The more info you can give us, the more helpful we can be.

Comment: @Alan I am using Windows and trying to open the .py file from within eclipse

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Install the PyDev plug-in for Eclipse:

http://www.rose-hulman.edu/class/csse/resources/Eclipse/eclipse-python-configuration.htm